# Apache NiFi QueryRecord SELECT Static Alias Column

Tags: sql, apache-nifi, apache-calcite

I want to import a file that has the following Avro schema assigned using Apache NiFi:

```
{
   "type" : "record",
   "namespace" : "SomeSpaceName",
   "name" : "SampleFile",
   "fields" : [
     { "name" : "PersonName" , "type" : "string" },
     { "name" : "PersonType" , "type" : "string" }
   ]
}
```

When I use the **QueryRecord** processor I want to have a static field in the output file so I can import it into MongoDB. The query is:

```
SELECT LOWER(PersonName) as _id,
'Male' as gender
FROM flowfile
```

The problem is Calcite will not add the new static field properly. It adds the name successfully but the new gender field only contains the first letter of the word:

```
| _id  | gender |
|------|--------|
| Eric | M      |
| Bill | M      |
| Chad | M      |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure `QueryRecord` processor writer *avro schema* have `_id,gender` fields included in it.

**`Writer Avro Schema:`**

```
{
   "type" : "record",
   "namespace" : "SomeSpaceName",
   "name" : "SampleFile",
   "fields" : [
     { "name" : "_id" , "type" : ["null","string"] },
     { "name" : "gender" , "type" : ["null","string"] }
   ]
}
```